# Android postdelayed handler could not initiate run

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, handler

I have the function to delay that locking the system current working. The startTimer function is initiating in the onCameraFrame() function that calls every frame captured. If my below timer is called, a flag is raised to lock the process.

```
public void startTimer() {

    if (!isLockSystem()) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        setLockSystem(true);
        Log.d(TAG_DEBUG, " The system is locked !");
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setLockSystem(false);
                        Log.d(TAG_DEBUG, " The system is unlocked !");
                    }
                }, 5000);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG_DEBUG, " The system is already locked !");
    }
}
```

The startTimer() is called, but never return to run() function. Whenever I triggered to startTimer, "The system is already locked" pressed.

What the safe method to implement a timer only once in the repetitive process that like capture continuous frames from camera.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is executing the handler in the onCameraFrame() method.

The proper way is the calling this function in the onCreate with trigger that is ShakeListener.